# Finding wpa2 key length

Tags: wireless, wpa2, wireshark, handshake

Is it possible to determine WPA key length through a successful handshake?

Below is a screen capture showing the packet capture session of interest as displayed in Wireshark:

[image]

My question came from that little phrase "WPA key length".
What does that phrase mean?

Comment: I'm confused about your question. You just did find that out.

Comment: I think he wants to get the length of the "Passphrase" and the answer it's no, please read PBKDF2 and how it works on WPA/2

Answer (score 1):

> My question came from that little phrase "WPA key length". What does
>   that phrase mean?

It appears to mean the length of the WPA key in bytes.

The "WPA Key" element is displayed in your figure right below the "WPA Key Length" element. The "WPA Key" appears in your figure as a string of 48 ASCII characters representing a sequence of 24 bytes. E.g., "DD" represents the byte `0xDD`, which is 221 in decimal. E.g, "16" represents the byte `0x16`, which is 22 in decimal.

Comment: can we use that to guess the length of the wpa key "plain text" ?

Comment: @hakim47 Why would you want the WPA key in "plain text" (ASCII?) You would just get gibberish text? It's a key, so it only works being in Hex, there's no point in converting it into something else, other than... maybe binary? IDK.

Comment: @Azteca no I meant that is itt possible to conclude the wpa key/wifi pass length from that